# Is there a way to make non headers anchor links using pandoc markup

Tags: anchor, pandoc

I'm trying to make an anchor link, but only see references to making anchor links using headers.

```
# Header
Go and see the [Header](#header)
```

However I want to link a specific word in a list. Is there a way to give a single word an anchor?

```
#. This phrase should be the anchor
Go and see number ([I.11](#this-phrase-should-be-the-anchor)
```

## Update

Still no luck with the original question. I think I might have to settle restructuring my documents with headers instead, which doesn't thrill me. I might have some documents that have deep subsections and html can't go beyond h6, but For the moment I will assume those are far and few inbetween.

The only solution I have found is a CSS that can modify the headers to include the alphanumerical numeration, which will make formatting much nicer than using lists since I have to do some funky hack for codes. Here is what that might potentially look like

```css
    body {
        counter-reset: section;
    }

    h1 {
        counter-reset: subsection;
    }

    h2 {
        counter-reset: subsubsection;
    }

    h1:before {
        counter-increment: section;

        content: "" counter(section,upper-roman) ". ";
    }

    h2:before {
        counter-increment: subsection;
        content: counter(section,upper-alpha) " ";
    }
    /* So on and so forth according to individual need*/
```

```html
<body>
  <h1> First section </h1>
      <h2>First Subsection</h2>
          <p> Enterprise to Kirk </p>
      <h2>Second Subsection</h2>
          <p> Come in Enterprise</p>
      <h2>Third Subsection</h2>
          <p> We are under attack.</p>
  <h1> Second section </h1>
       <h2>First Subsection</h2>
      <h2>Second Subsection</h2>
      <h2>Third Subsection</h2>
</body>
```

I also learned how to attach a css file with pandoc
Add the --css filepath.css to the command line

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can assign `id` to all the elements with [attributes in pandoc's internal AST](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs#L200) (in newer pandoc versions this includes [images and links](http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-link_attributes)).

You can also always use [divs or spans](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans) as well:

```
This is [a span]{#foo}

That can be [referenced with a link](#foo)
```

Comment: I couldn't find the reference in the pandoc readme saying explicitly that you could add ids to any element. Great! I think for now however I will use the technique that I described above as I don't like having too much markup in the texts. But this is the answer I was looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: @Mallow glad I could help! Just to be clear: unfortunately, not _all_ elements support attributes yet, I rephrased my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @mb21 Thank you for the update, this works perfectly and is much cleaner than using `<span id=...`!